# Two linearly independent subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

I’d like to show the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space, $E$ a finite subset of $V$ and $I$ the set of linearly independent subsets of $E$. Further let $A \in I$ and $B \in I$, with $|B| = |A| + 1$. Then there exists an $e \in B \setminus A$ such that $A \cup \{e\} \in I$.

I don’t really have an idea of how to proof this. Why must there be a vector in $B$ that is not a linear combination of the vectors in $A$?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there were not any vectors $e\in B$ satisfying the condition, that is, for every vector $v \in B$, $A \cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent, then every vector in $B$ is a linear combination of the vector is $A$, which means $Span B \subset Span A$, which is a contradiction, since we would have to have $dim Span B \le dim Span A$ which would mean $|B|\le|A|$.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for you help.

Comment: I still dont quite understand, why dim(Span(B)) <= dim(Span(A)) implies |B| <= |A|.

Comment: And isn't the dimension only defined for the vector space itself and not a span of vectors?

Comment: Well, the span of vectors is, itself, a vectors space (in fact, any vector subspace is a vector space), and the dimension of a vector space is just the number of vectors in a base for this vector space (a base is a set that spans the vector space and is linear independent). So, since $B$ and $A$ are linearly independent sets which obviously span their spans, $B$ and $A$ are bases for $SpanB$ and $SpanA$, respectively, it follows that, dim$SpanB$=|$B$| and dim$SpanA$=|$A$|. Do you understand it now?

Comment: I should have pointed out that the dimension of a vector space is unique, that is, any two bases for a vector space have the same cardinality.